# What is a good way to create a shared context for Web Components in a parent-child situation using Redux?

Tags: redux, web-component

When using Redux with React we're able to use react-redux which internally uses React's context API to make the store available to all HoCs created with connect.

I'm playing around with Web Components to evaluate how feasible it is to use primarily Web Components for building your application but still wanted a way to deal with state management (in Polymer they recommed using the mediator pattern and Redux is a type of global mediator).

So far I'm able to have a component create the store and pass it to a child component to use. This has the limitation that I will need to pass around the store to every container component, and even pass it through presentational components if they need to then pass it to another container.

So what I want to achieve is a way to make the store available to all container components that live under the Store component in the tree, preferably without making the store a global variable.
I imagined creating something similar to the react-redux connect component but since that one relies on React context I'm trying to find ideas for how to create a shared object.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your class in an iife function and declaring a variable outside of the scope of the class as well as assigning a property of the class to the external variable will create a singleton mechanism for sharing data between instances of an element. You would then include that element inside of the template of any other element and bind to it normally. Here's an example: https://github.com/firmfirm/f-singleton/blob/master/f-singleton.html